# Python pandas function applied to all pairwise combinations of rows

Tags: python, pandas, apply, correlation

I'm trying to run a function (correlation) on all pairwise combinations of rows within a pandas dataframe:

```
stats = dict()
for l in itertools.combinations(dat.index.tolist(),2):
    stats[l] = pearsonr(dat.loc[l[0],:], dat.loc[l[1],:]) # stores (r, p)
```

Of course this is quite slow, and I'm wondering how to do the equivalent through the use of something like `apply()` or otherwise.

Note: I know I can directly find the correlation of the dataframe with the [pandas corr()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) function, however it doesn't return the associated p-value (which I need for filtering purposes)

Comment: If you look in the source of [`pearsonr`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.1/scipy/stats/stats.py#L2514) you will find that it takes just a few lines of code to calculate p-value if you have correlation coefficient. It should not be very difficult to make a `function` that you can use with `.apply(function)`.

Comment: consider changing your title to something more specific :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you some speed-up.  Define a function `Pearson`, modified from the docs in Primer's link:

```
def Pearson(r, n=len(dat)):
    r = max(min(r, 1.0), -1.0)
    df = n - 2
    if abs(r) == 1.0:
        prob = 0.0
    else:
        t_squared = r**2 * (df / ((1.0 - r) * (1.0 + r)))
        prob = betai(0.5*df, 0.5, df/(df+t_squared))

    return (r,prob)
```

Use [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) which does element-wise operations on `dat.corr`. You are passing the correlation coefficient `r` to `Pearson`:

```
np.random.seed(10)
dat = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 5))
dat[0] = np.arange(5) # seed two correlated cols
dat[1] = np.arange(5) # ^^^

dat.corr().applymap(Pearson)

    0   1   2   3   4
0   (1.0, 0.0)  (1.0, 0.0)  (0.713010395675, 0.176397305541)    (0.971681374885, 0.00569624513678)  (0.0188249871501, 0.97603269768)
1   (1.0, 0.0)  (1.0, 0.0)  (0.713010395675, 0.176397305541)    (0.971681374885, 0.00569624513678)  (0.0188249871501, 0.97603269768)
2   (0.713010395675, 0.176397305541)    (0.713010395675, 0.176397305541)    (1.0, 0.0)  (0.549623945218, 0.337230071385)    (-0.280514871109, 0.647578381153)
3   (0.971681374885, 0.00569624513678)  (0.971681374885, 0.00569624513678)  (0.549623945218, 0.337230071385)    (1.0, 0.0)  (0.176622737448, 0.77629170593)
4   (0.0188249871501, 0.97603269768)    (0.0188249871501, 0.97603269768)    (-0.280514871109, 0.647578381153)   (0.176622737448, 0.77629170593)     (1.0, 0.0)
```

You do see speedup with this method when `dat` is large, but it's still pretty slow because of the element-wise operations.

```
np.random.seed(10)
dat = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 100))

%%timeit
dat.corr().applymap(Pearson)

10 loops, best of 3: 118 ms per loop

%%timeit
stats = dict()

for l in combinations(dat.index.tolist(),2):
    stats[l] = pearsonr(dat.loc[l[0],:], dat.loc[l[1],:])

1 loops, best of 3: 1.56 s per loop
```